# AngularJS - How to hide a div when clicking outside of it

Tags: angularjs, hide, show-hide

I have an angularjs application which use to open and hide a hidden div.

Here is a jsfiddle with a sample - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f3feU/6/)

```
$scope.openLogin = function(){
    $scope.userLogin = true;
};
 $scope.hideLoginContainer = function(){
    $scope.userLogin = false;
};
```

When I click on the "Click Here" link it will show the user login div, so I need to hide this div when I click outside. The issue I am facing here is even i click inside the user login div it will hide.

any one know of any good ideas? 
Thanks

Comment: Guess someone has edited the sample fiddle provided in the question. That works perfectly fine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be worked, just edit:  `<div hide-login="hideLoginContainer()" class="loginBox" ng-show="userLogin" style="display:none;" >`

Answer (score 1):

You can check originalTarget, or srcElement in `$document.bind('click')` event handler and if it will match `loginBox` element, then you don't hide it.

Edit: I just realized... you have to use `stopPropagation()` also on loginBox element, it should be enough to fix hiding when you click inside the login box